# AppVersion Struct & VersionParse Exception

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am working on an app that will interact with assembly (app) versions. I created a struct for that, along with an exception for parsing error.

Here's the code:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class VersionParseException : Exception
    {
        public VersionParseException()
        { }

        public VersionParseException(string message)
            : base(message)
        { }

        public VersionParseException(string message, Exception innerException)
            : base(message, innerException)
        { }

        protected VersionParseException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context)
        { }

    }

    public struct AppVersion
    {
        int _majorVersion;
        public int MajorVersion
        {
            get { return _majorVersion; }
            set
            {
                _majorVersion = value;
            }
        }

        int _minorVersion;
        public int MinorVersion
        {
            get { return _minorVersion; }
            set
            {
                _minorVersion = value;
            }
        }

        int _buildNumber;
        public int BuildNumber
        {
            get { return _buildNumber; }
            set
            {
                _buildNumber = value;
            }
        }

        int _revision;
        public int Revision
        {
            get { return _revision; }
            set
            {
                _revision = value;
            }
        }

        public string Version
        {
            get { return MajorVersion.ToString() + "." + MinorVersion.ToString() + "." + BuildNumber.ToString() + "." + Revision.ToString(); }
            set
            {
                try
                {
                    MajorVersion = int.Parse(value.Split('.')[0]);
                    MinorVersion = int.Parse(value.Split('.')[1]);
                    BuildNumber = int.Parse(value.Split('.')[2]);
                    Revision = int.Parse(value.Split('.')[3]);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    throw new VersionParseException("Invalid App Version", exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any better way to handle AppVersions and exceptions occurring in the process of using it?

And here's an example of using the struct:

```
AppVersion version1;
version1.Version = "0.500.965.201";
Console.WriteLine(version1.MinorVersion); // outputs "500"
version1.BuildNumber = 753;
Console.WriteLine(version1.Version);      // outputs "0.500.753.201"
```

Another example on throwing the exception:

```
AppVersion version2;
version2.Version = "0.blabla.987.test"; //Throws VersionParseException
```

Answer (score 5):

> I am working on an app that will interact with assembly (app) versions

There's a class, [`System.Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx), that might be suitable for your needs. `System.Version`:

> Represents the version number of an assembly, operating system, or the common language runtime.

It has `Major`, `Minor`, `Build`, and `Revision` properties.

If you still want to roll your own, my advice is to

- Make `AppVersion` immutable
- Be stricter about the values you allow
- Implement `IEquatable<AppVersion>`
- Consider implementing `IComparable<AppVersion>`

---

In general, you should avoid mutable structs.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **X DO NOT** define mutable value types.
>
> Mutable value types have several problems. For example, when a property getter returns a value type, the caller receives a copy. Because the copy is created implicitly, developers might not be aware that they are mutating the copy, and not the original value.

See also: [Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

---

With the code as written, this works just fine:

```
appVersion.Version = "   +123 . -4236 . +0 . -789";
```

Use the overloads of `int.Parse`/`int.TryParse` that take a [`NumberStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) argument. If you provide constructors as suggested below, check that the values passed in are non-negative.

---

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **✓ DO** implement `IEquatable<T>` on value types.
>
> The `Object.Equals` method on value types causes boxing, and its default implementation is not very efficient, because it uses reflection. `Equals` can have much better performance and can be implemented so that it will not cause boxing.

---

I find it hard to imagine not ever wanting to compare app versions, so you will probably want to implement `IComparable<AppVersion>`.

---

I would recommending getting rid of the `Version` property entirely. Instead, provide one or more constructors like

```
public AppVersion(int majorVersion, int minorVersion)

public AppVersion(int majorVersion, int minorVersion, int buildNumber)

...
```

and then provide static methods `AppVersion Parse(string)` and `bool TryParse(string, out AppVersion)`.

---

Also, you should be aware of the existence of [auto-implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Comment: I'm not very experienced in .NET, how do I go about implementing IEquatable and IComparable?

Comment: And if I use such contructors and remove the version property, you think I should implement my own toString () to AppVersion then right?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already throwing your own exception, you should use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead. I know, you want to have an `InnerException` on your `VersionException`, but consider: what value does it add? It also only indicates a problem with *one* element, whereas if you use `int.TryParse`, you can indicate to the user *all* the elements that had problems. In my opinion, that's a much more helpful exception.

Plus, `Exception` catching and throwing is slow. There's no need to catch an exception if you can avoid it completely.

You should also consider adding the appropriate attributes for [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (and the like). I find that I use this (and [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) way more often than any others, but they require special attribute management.

Comment: But what should I do incase TryParse fail? Throw exception? Set version data to null or 0s?

Comment: That's when you throw your *custom* exception. You can go through the `int.TryParse` for *all four* elements, and then throw **one** exception to indicate **all** of the `TryParse` calls that failed.

Comment: Oh, I see. thank you for the suggestions. you can never have enough knowledge!

Comment: @WalidNawfalSabihi Exactly, some people would have been upset by this, but I'm glad your not one of that some! :)

Comment: I hope so... ;)